# How to find the Lipschitz constant that verifies that g is a contraction?

Tags: numerical-methods

Suppose you have $f(x)=e^{-2x}-1=0$ then an iterative form of this equation would be $x_{n+1} = g( x_n )=\ln(2 x_n +1)$, by the IVT I know $f(x)$ has a root t in the interval $[1,2]$ and the fixed point of $g(x)$ between $1$ & $2$ is $t$. Hence, how do I show that the iterative form of $f(x)$ converges to this to this $t$ by showing that $g$ is a contraction on $[1,2]$ and how do I find the Lipschitz constant to verify this?

Comment: *how do I find the Lipschitz constant* --- There are (uncountably) infinitely many Lipschitz constants whenever a Lipschitz constant exists, and if by "**the** Lipschitz constant" you mean the smallest such constant, then (assuming I'm not overlooking something) you don't need the smallest such constant to verify that $g$ is a contraction (you only need a Lipschitz constant that is less than $1).$

Comment: Please check your equations, the equation for $f$ gives $x=0$ as only solution, which is different from the fixed-point equation which has an additional solution.